# How can I parallel-ize an algorithm on a machine with multiple processors?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, parallel-processing, mergesort

- [Intel Core2Duo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core_2), for example is supposed to have a single die but **two cores**.
- So, it should be possible to control what is processed on which core, which means that it is possible to instruct my algorithm to use the two cores in parallel.

The question is how?

Do I need to go down at the kernel level to do this, or is there a simpler way? To be more concrete, what does it take to implement a dual-core-merge-sort?

Comment: LOL, I read that as paralyze  :-(

Comment: I think this is a very real question with some excellent answers!

Answer (score 3):

Judging by your past questions, I'd say you're looking to implement in C/C++, but I believe the answer is roughly the same regardless of language.

If you want to parallelize any operation, make it multithreaded.  You can have as many parallel, concurrent threads as you have cores.

Here's a related question:
[How to implement divide and conquer algorithms in C# using multithreading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604991/how-to-implement-divide-and-conquer-algorithms-in-c-using-multithreading)

As I understand it, binding a particular thread to a core or processor is called [processor affinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity).  It's generally not a good idea, because the purpose of the operating system is to juggle threads between processors.  It's unlikely that you'll do a better job of this than the OS can.

Comment: For fine-grained parallelism, you want to use some sort of thread pool and not pay the startup cost of new threads for every parallel task.

Comment: I have done quite a bit of work with processor affinity and believe me, you definitely can do a better job than the OS, provided that you properly analyze your problem, but the same holds true for threading.

Answer (score 3):

To implement an algorithm that takes advantage of multiple cores, consider [OpenMP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ca2w8dk.aspx).

Of course, algorithms that have strong data dependencies may not parallelize well.

Comment: @polemon: Is there any eason for this considering OpenMP is generally simpler to use (at least for easy parallizable problems, but since this topic seems to be geared towards beginners, thats (hopefully) what we are talking about)

Comment: OpenMP is more suitable for fine-grained parallelism, pthreads for less-fine parallelism, fork for somewhat coarse-grained parallelism, and distributed systems (clusters) for extremely coarse parallelism.  This question is quite fine-grained and so I think you'd be crazy to use fork to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are looking to assigning threads to each of the core ..
This is a detailed description of what can be done and how to do it.

[Processor affinity](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-affinity.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[A Specimen of Parallel Programming: Parallel Merge Sort Implementation](http://penguin.ewu.edu/~trolfe/ParallelMerge/ParallelMerge.html). And here is one in [Erlang](http://www.planeterlang.org/en/planet/article/Parallel_merge_sort_in_Erlang/). For more precise answers, you have to ask a more precise question.

Answer (score 0):

It depends in what programming language you want to achieve this. For example for:

- Python - use [multiprocessing](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-multiprocessing/) or [parallel python](http://www.parallelpython.com/) lib.
- C#/.NET - use [parallel framework](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx) for [multi-core](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_Extensions) apps.
- newLISP - just use [spawn()/other stuff](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introduction_to_newLISP/Multitasking) for same goal.
- C - you may use [POSIX threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads) and such
- etc., etc., etc....

Just choose language and look for parallel processing abilities in that language.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

While POSIX threads (pthreads) are probably a good idea to start, this is not exclusive.

Multithreading in C isn't actually trivial, hence, I'd advice `fork()`.

start one worker fork for each CPU with a subsection of you'r mergesort algorithm, and then reassemble them in the manager fork.

When working towards a parallel solution, I consider forks before threads, since they're easier to implement, and you get a quick preliminary result. Once that works, you might want to take some time and work with pthreads.